# Cloud Foundry CLI path on Windows

Tags: path, command-line-interface, websphere, cloud-foundry

I followed the IBM manual to install CF CLI from the github "Installers" section.
After installation I restarted. Then in the CLI if I type `cf` it says command not found.

So I thought I have to add an evnironment path to the executable.
But in the path `C:\Program Files\IBM\Cloud\bin` there is no `cf` file, only bluemix.exe, bx.exe, ibmcloud.exe and imbcloud-analytics.exe. I couldn't find it in the AppData/local folder either, and the IBM documentation there is no mention of this.

Does anyone know where to find the executable or how else to fix this?

Comment: As far as I remember there is no separate for IBM Cloud `cf` tool, but you have to invoke cf related commands via `ibmcloud` , like `ibmcloud cf ...` . See this https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cli-ibmcloud_cli

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gas' comment, I was able to login using this:

`ibmcloud login -a https://api.ng.bluemix.net`

So it seems like we need to substitute `cf` for `ibmcloud`